# In Java how can I access a variable from outside the anonymous class

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   SomeClass something = new SomeClass();
   something.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(){
         doSomething(i);
      }
   });
}
```

I am not allowed to use the variable `i`, Eclipse suggest me make the `i` `final`, but I cannot do that because I need it to iterate right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy `i` to a `final` variable in the loop body.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   final int j = i;
   SomeClass something = new SomeClass();
   something.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(){
         doSomething(j);
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: +1 this seems logical

Comment: +1 most IDEs will do this for you as an auto-fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
loop with i
  final int k = i
  annonymousClass
```